# Jetty 9.3.6: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator

Tags: java, jetty, basic-authentication

I am trying to provide HTTP BASIC authentication for my webapp running on Jetty 9.3.6. I followed the instructions in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/configuring-security-authentication.html) and it appeared like my authentication mechanism should be based out of JAAS. But my auth fails for a `No LoginService` error (see details below).

I followed the instructions in [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.2.6.v20141205/jaas-support.html) and ended up with this `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml` in my gradle sources:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
metadata-complete="false"
version="3.1">

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
 </login-config>

</web-app>
```

And I had to also add a context descriptor which I place in `src/main/webapp/myWebApp.xml` (this unwraps in `${jetty.base}/webapp/` and the `web.xml` unwraps in `${jetty.base}/webapp/WEB-INF/` though they  are unwrapped when I deploy this war even though I choose to `extractWAR` below):

```
<Configure id='wac' class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/myWebApp</Set>
  <Set name="war">/opt/jetty/someJettyBase/webapps/myWebApp.war</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>

  <Set name="securityHandler">
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
     <Set name="loginService">
       <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.JAASLoginService">
         <Set name="name">myRealm</Set>
         <Set name="loginModuleName">xyz</Set>
       </New>
     </Set>
    </New>
  </Set>

</Configure>
```

To tie the JAAS to my login module, I do this in `${jetty.base}/etc/login.conf` in my jetty deployment:

```
xyz {
com.webapp.MyLoginService required debug=true;
};
```

And lastly, I added `jaas` as a service to jetty using

```
$ java -jar --add-to-startd=jaas
```

and confirmed that it worked (file in `${jetty.base}/startd/jaas.ini`).

Unfortunately, when I start Jetty, I see that it has not correctly worked, as I see this:

```
19 Jan 2016 21:29:08.811 WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:526) Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@27c20538{/myWebApp,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-443-myWebApp.war-_myWebApp-any-8865406277141986908.dir/webapp/,STARTING}{/myWebApp.war}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No LoginService for org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator@5762806e in org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@17c386de
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.LoginAuthenticator.setConfiguration(LoginAuthenticator.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.doStart(SecurityHandler.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler.doStart(ConstraintSecurityHandler.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
```

MyLoginService.java:

```
package com.webapp;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import org.eclipse.jetty.security.LoginService;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.IdentityService;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.UserIdentity;
import org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultUserIdentity;

public class MyLoginService implements LoginService
{
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger (MyLoginService.class.getName ());

    private IdentityService identityService;

    public MyLoginService (IdentityService identityService)
    {
        this.identityService = identityService;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
      return "name";
    }

    @Override
    public UserIdentity login(String username, Object credentials, ServletRequest request)
    {
        log.debug ("MyLoginService.login: username received {}", username);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(UserIdentity user)
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public IdentityService getIdentityService()
    {
        return identityService;
     }

     @Override
     public void setIdentityService(IdentityService service)
      {
      }

     @Override
     public void logout(UserIdentity user)
     {
     }
}
```

Any insights into this is deeply appreciated.

What am I missing?

Thanks!